# Expression to get LINQ with Contains to EF for SQL IN() where on entities child's property equals value

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

I have a simple need to filter all parents out of the returned collection where there is no match on a field, that is called by name from a string, doesn't match a value presented.  What I am after is if `parent` object has `child` object, and that `child` objects property `"foo"`(called by string) doesn't or does equal a value `bar`, the `parent` object is filtered from the collection appropriately.

**Here is my linq ef call**

```
var field = "bar";
var values = new List<string>{"foo","fuYu"};
var dataPage = _aim_context.ae_s_bld_c.AsNoTracking();
var result = dataPage.Where(x => 
                              DbHelper.byPropertyContains(x.udfs, field, values)
                           );
// NOTE `udfs` is a ONE-to-ONE with `ae_s_bld_c`
```

**What I am looking to see is something like the SQL of**

```
SELECT [m].[id],[m.udfs].[bar],
FROM [dbo].[ae_s_bld_c] AS [m]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[ae_s_bld_c_udf] AS [m.udfs]
        ON ([m].[multitenant_id] = [m.udfs].[multitenant_id])
WHERE ([m].[multitenant_id] = 1.0)
    AND ([m.udfs].[bar] IN ('foo','fuYu')) --< Goal line
```

The way I have approached this was to get an expression set up to take the `List<string>` and make the SQL.  I have read near 50 articles and SO posts, but have not figured out exactly why I am not getting this just yet as everyone seems to have different ideas, and most are not in line with dotnet core 2.1+ it seems.

Here is what I am sitting at currently after many many iterations. *NOTE:* it is a little different from what I am after as I am giving my current trail.

**My current context linq try**

```
//...
dataPage = dataPage.Where(DbHelper.byPropertyContains<ae_s_bld_c>("udfs", field, values));
//...
```

I think it would be better if it was like the first example I put up, but that was what I have landed on since I have had a time lining it up with `x=>x.udfs`, both as `x=> funName(x.udfs)` and  `x=> x.udfs.funName()`

**My static method to build the expression**

```
public static class DbHelper
{
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> byPropertyContains<T>(string node, string field, List<string> value) {
//trying to take parent item and get it's property by string name because
// doing the function in linq like x=>x.udfs was not working right
// but that is the prefered I think
        var property_parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");
        var property = Expression.PropertyOrField(property_parameter, node);
        var selector_parameter = Expression.Parameter(property.Type, "y");
        var selector = Expression.PropertyOrField(selector_parameter, field);
        var methodInfo = typeof(List<string>).GetMethod("Contains", new Type[] {
            typeof(string)
        });
        var list = Expression.Constant(value, typeof(List<string>));
        var body = Expression.Call(methodInfo, list, selector);
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, selector_parameter);
    }
}
```

### Update

Per the request of @NetMage I have tried to work backwards with LINQpad.  I think I am close but it is hard to tell with teh output.  I am putting it up here for reference.  To be clear, the property name of the child will be a string of the name.  The best outcome is I could have a name like `udfs.foo` where I can test on any level if the values contain by string name, but really ok with it starting here,

```
var result = dataPage.Where(x => 
                              DbHelper.byPropertyContains(x.udfs, field, values)
                           );
```

[image: output of LINQpad]

Comment: I suggest getting LINQPad and comparing you `byPropertyContains` results to what a manually created lambda (compiler translated to `Expression`) looks like.

Comment: In LINQPad, do `Expression<Func<ae_s_bld_c, bool>> f = x => values.Contains(x.udfs.bar);` and then `f.Dump()` and compare the output to your build method's result.

Comment: Not that I am aware of - did you define the type `ae_s_bld_c`, did you define `values`?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see what's the question/issue here. All I see is the desired SQL and your current code, but not what you are getting with it and what's the problem - e.g. SQL, exception, something else?

Comment: @IvanStoev I can't give you a specific error because it would just be on the current iteration posted.  I keep trying new iterations so I am not even on that version per-say.  That would distract from the question I believe anyway.   The issue is that by all accounts I should be able to do a contains on the child entity by property name, but all articles in SO, or just googling is outdated or incomplete and I keep missing the key factor to get it to work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let start from here. You need an equivalent of something like this

```
var result = dataPage.Where(x => values.Contains(x.udfs.{field}));
```

where `field` is a string returning property dynamically specified by name.

In EF Core you don't even need to deal with building expresions by hand, because EF Core provides a special SQL translatable function for accessing simple properties by name called [EF.Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.ef.property?view=efcore-2.1).

With that method the solution is simple as that:

```
var result = dataPage
   .Where(x => values.Contains(EF.Property<string>(x.udfs, field)));
```

Comment: OMG... I have google'd and google'd and was looking for that right there the whole darn time.  Thank you!!!!